# How to check if there is key needed application state in asp.net (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Global.asax i have:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    //Key is Login name and value is password
    Application["dan"] = "123";
    Application["rafi"] = "123";
    Application["nick"] = "123";
    Application["dave"] = "123";


}
```

Now i have login.aspx page where i need to check login and password that is in application state. I have two textboxes and button. I need to check if value typed in texboxUserName.text exists in application state, values needed to be -dan, rafi, nick or dave. how do i do that?:) 
 It's an exercise in our school..

**UPD**
Ok i did it:) thx for help

protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    string name=txtUserName.Text;
    string pass = txtPassword.Text;




    foreach (string key in Application.AllKeys)
    {
        if (key == name)
        {
            string curectName = name;

            if ((string) Application[curectName] == pass)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "pass don't match";
            }

        }

        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "no name";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Weird way of authentication, why like that?

Comment: So if someone types in the name of some other application state variable along with the expected value of that variable, then they are authenticated? This is terrible security! I hope this class isn't trying to teach security, unless this is given as a counter-example. ;)

Comment: No :) It's not.. We learn application state, best example of application state is "click counter", but our teacher wanted us to do something different.

Answer (score 0):

Similar as you add it:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Application[texboxUserName.Text]))
{
    string password = Application[texboxUserName.Text].ToString();
}
```

Comment: You can also make password a string and add .ToString() at the end. Seems logical :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try:

```
if(Application[texboxUserName.text] != null)
{
   if(Application[texboxUserName.text] == textboxPassword) 
   {
        return true;
   }
   else
   {
        return false;
   }
}
```

i am writing from head, i didn try this code.

`texboxUserName.text` and `textboxPassword` are values of textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

If the entry in Application does not exist, the value will be Null. You can do it on one line, but for clarity, here's a complicated example:

```
if(Application[strUserName] != Null){
  // Got username entry
  if(Application[strUserName] == strPassword){
     // Do something
  }
}
```

That said, it's generally not a good idea to keep usernames and passwords in application state.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (Application[textboxUserName.Text] != null 
        && Application[textboxUserName.text] == textboxPassword.Text)
    {
       // username + password exist
    }
```